# Intercalar listas estáticas em C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>  
#define tam 10  
#define TAM2 20  



typedef int Apontador;


typedef struct{  
    int item;  
}Elemento;

typedef struct{  
    Elemento elemento[tam];  
    Elemento intercalar[TAM2];// feito para intercalar as listas   
    Apontador inicio, fim;  
}Lista;


void startList(Lista* lst){
    lst->inicio=0;
    lst->fim=lst->inicio;
}

int insertList(Elemento E, Lista* lst){
    
    if(lst->fim>tam-1){
        printf("Lista cheia\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        lst->elemento[lst->fim]=E;
        lst->fim++;
        return 1;
    }

}


int insertListAlt(Elemento E, Lista* lst){
    
    if(lst->fim>TAM2-1){
        printf("Lista cheia\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("\n elemento inserido: %d\n",E);
        lst->intercalar[lst->fim]=E;
        lst->fim++;
        return 1;
    }
    
}


void ImprimirLista(Lista* lst){
    int aux;
    
    for(aux=lst->inicio;aux<=(lst->fim-1);aux++){
        printf("\n%d\t",lst->elemento[aux].item);       
    }
        
}

void ImprimirListaAlt(Lista* lst){
    int aux;
    
    for(aux=0;aux<TAM2;aux++){
        printf("\n%d\t",lst->intercalar[aux].item);     
    }
        
}


int VerificaOrdenacao(Lista* lst, int n){
    int aux,k=1;
    
    for(aux=lst->inicio; aux<=(lst->fim-1);aux++){
        
        if(lst->elemento[aux+1].item > lst->elemento[aux].item){
            k++;
            if(k==n){
                printf("Ordenacao crescente.");
                return 1;
            }
                    
        }
    //  printf("contador k: %d\t;",k);
    }
    
    for(aux=lst->inicio; aux<=(lst->fim-1);aux++){
        
        if(lst->elemento[aux+1].item < lst->elemento[aux].item){
            k++;
            if(k==n){
                printf("Ordenacao decrescente.");
                return 1;
            }
                    
        }
    //  printf("contador k: %d\t;",k);
    }
    
    return 0;

    
    
}


int listasIguais(Lista* lst1, Lista* lst2){
    
    int aux;
    
    for(aux=0;aux<=tam;aux++){// REVER ESSA REPETIÇÃO
    
        if(lst1->elemento[aux].item!=lst2->elemento[aux].item){
            return 0;
            printf("erro");
        }
    }
    return lst1==lst2;
    
    
}


int lst_copia(Lista* lst1, Lista* lst2){
    int aux;
    
    for(aux=0;aux<=tam; aux++){// rever repetição
        lst2->elemento[aux]=lst1->elemento[aux];
        insertList(lst2->elemento[aux],lst2);
    }
    return 1;
}


int lst_inverte(Lista* lst1, Lista* lst2){
    int aux,i=0;
    
    for(aux=tam-1;aux>=0;aux--){
        lst2->elemento[i]=lst1->elemento[aux];
        insertList(lst2->elemento[i],lst2);
        i++;// rever
    }
    i=0;
    return 1;
}

int lst_intercalar(Lista* lst1, Lista* lst2,Lista* itc){
    int aux;
    
    for(aux=0;aux<TAM2;aux++){
        
        if(aux%2==0){   
            insertListAlt(lst2->elemento[aux], itc);    
        }
        if(aux%2!=0){   
            insertListAlt(lst1->elemento[aux], itc);    
        }   
        
    }

    return 1;
    
}



main(){  
    Elemento a1,a2;    
    Lista lstnum1, lstnum2,intercal;  
    startList(&lstnum1);  
    startList(&lstnum2);  
    startList(&intercal);  
    
        
    printf("\nPreencha a lista 1 com numeros inteiros\n");
    
    for(int i=0;i <tam; i++){
        printf("\nInformar o %d.o numero: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a1.item);
        insertList(a1,&lstnum1);
    }
        
    printf("\nPreencha a lista 2 com numeros inteiros\n");
    
    for(int i=0;i <tam; i++){
        printf("\nInformar o %d.o numero: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a2.item);
        insertList(a2,&lstnum2);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    
//  listasIguais(&lstnum1,&lstnum2);
    
//  VerificaOrdenacao(&lstnum1, tam);
    
//  ImprimirLista(&lstnum1);
    
//  lst_copia(&lstnum1,&lstnum2);
    
//  lst_inverte(&lstnum1, &lstnum2);
    
//  ImprimirLista(&lstnum2);
    
    lst_intercalar(&lstnum1, &lstnum2,&intercal);
    ImprimirListaAlt(&intercal);
    
    
    
}
```

Pessoal, não estou conseguindo intercalar duas listas estáticas. Como tinha criado duas listas de tamanho 10, para intercalar criei outra lista só que de tamanho 20. Para a intercalação defini que se o índice for par, vai para uma lista e se for ímpar vai para outra. Só que está ocorrendo um erro e esses números não estão sendo inseridos.

Answer (score 0):

Agradeço a todos que visualizaram. Meu erro está na repetição da função lst_intercalar. Como preencherei duas listas estáticas, ambas nos endereços que vão de 0 a 9(10 elementos), dentro da função, só vão ser inseridos 10 valores ao invés dos 20.